# VACUUM sqlite database from the SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, sqlite, vacuum

My app's database keeps growing and I want to perform a VACUUM to retrieve some lost space. From what I've read VACUUM does not run if there are other transactions.

My question is: how do I run the command from my SQLiteOpenHelper? is something like `db.execSQL("VACUUM")` work? But how do I get some sort of progress while doing this so I can block the UI with a loading dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `VACUUM` like any other SQL commands; `execSQL()` will work.

However, there is not mechanism to track the progress.

And SQLite automatically reuses free pages, so `VACUUM` is unlikely to help. (It is useful only if you have deleted a large amount of data, and know that you will not insert new data again.)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable info.